# Сохранение ключей в базе данных

Tags: c#, rsa

Хочу сохранять пароли в базе с помощью RSA.
Я так понял по примеру - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.100).aspx,
создается провайдер и по нему генерируются приватный и общий ключи, для роботы с паролем. Вопросы:
1. Возможно ли создать много общих ключей с одним приватным или наоборот(если да, прошу код)?
2. Если на в.1 ответ нет, то у нас в базе есть по сути много приватных и общих ключей. Как их сохранять в базе, отдельная таблица или запихивать в таблицу Users?
3. Стоит ли вообще сохранять ключи(и использовать RSA) в базе или сохранять их где-то в другом месте? Так как если злоумышленник имеет доступ к базе то по сути он нашел эти ключи и его уже не остановить.

Comment: А что вы собираетесь потом с этими ключами делать для юзеров?

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает MD5?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не корректно выразился, а чем вас не устраивает хеширование?

Comment: вот тут можно почитать: https://habr.com/post/210760/

Comment: Нужно именно асинхронное шифрование для пароля, заказчик настаивает.

Comment: Я б использовал MD5,  но он хочет именно RSA. Типа MD5 старий и простой.

Comment: Скажите заказчику, что если он хочет огромную дыру в безопасности, то можно и шифровать. Но по уму пароли только хешируются.

Comment: Объясните заказчику, что хеширование, это более "сильное" шифрование нежели асимметричное, потому что данные вообще невозможно расшифровать.

Answer (score 0):

"Ответ на третий вопрос"

Я всего лишь хочу указать вашу(как я считаю) ошибку в выборе "функции"(если так можно выразитья) шифрования Ваших данных...
Ваш выбор пал на RSA, но чем он так примечателен?

Предлагаю Вам использовать "md5", это функция хеширует ваши данные так, что расшифровать их практически невозможно... Почему практически?Потому что на данный момент в интернете существуют  сайты в которых занесена база данных захешированных строк и если у Вас пароль будет совпадать с базой данных(это случится только если Ваш пароль легок.Например :"123"), то сайт вывелет пароль...Поэтому создайте пароль, хотя бы 'средней сложности' и используйте md5. Ваши данные уже никто не расшифрует...

Спасибо!)))Поддержите лайком...

Comment: Я бы добавил что при желании можно достать любую информацию, но вопрос в средствах и времени , так что MD5 вполне хорош.

Comment: Можно соли присыпать, чтоб простые пароли тоже не давали известные хеши